# 모두 versus 다 as an adverb. What is the difference in this practical example?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, difference, adverbs

Is there any difference in nuance between 모두 and 다? Are there times when it is more appropriate to use one over the other?

Here is a practical example I have been looking at:

> 재료는 모두 준비되어 있습니다.

versus

> 재료는 다 준비되어 있습니다.

Comment: 그래 모두 다 알고 싶은 것이다

Answer (score 2):

In many cases they are interchangeable, but I think 모두 has a *tendency* to describe multiple distinct items.

So, for example, (A) below is more likely to mean "Everybody drank water," so that it describes multiple distinct persons.  (B) is more likely to mean "[Somebody] drank all the water."  (However, as I said, they are just tendencies and I feel that both sentences can be used for both situations.)

> (A) 물을 **모두** 마셨어요.
>
> (B) 물을 **다** 마셨어요.

Also, 다 frequently means "fully; to the full possible extent; (colloquially) almost".  When used this way, usually, it cannot be replaced by 모두.  For example,

> 부산까지 **다** 왔습니다. = We're (almost) arriving at Busan.
>
> 부산까지 **모두** 왔습니다. = Everyone arrived at Busan.
>
> 컴퓨터가 **다**/완전히 맛이 갔네요. = The computer is totally broken.
>
> 컴퓨터가 **모두** 맛이 갔네요. = All the computers are broken.

Answer (score 1):

In counting, 모두, 다 as a adverb have almost same meaning (cf. 2)). But 모두 can be a pronoun and 다 have more wide usage as a adverb in estimating degree.

> 1) 모두 is pronoun

누가 대표가 될지는 우리반 모두의 관심거리다

It is our interest that someone will be a representative.

누가 대표가 될지는 우리반 다의 관심거리다 (X)

> 2) When things satisfying given condition can be **counted** at that time, then we can use both, i.e., 모두, 다.

회원들은 다 참석할 것이다.

Members all will participate

재료는 다 (=모두 다=모두) 준비되어 있습니다.

All which is needed are prepared.

다 이해 할 수 있다.

I can understand all.

> 3) In further, 다 indicates a **completion** of given one project.

목적지에 다 왔다.

We come near at the goal place.

오늘 일은 다 끝났다.

Work for today is completely done.

@@ If we planed two works, for instance, swimming and buying a pencil, then we can use the following ? 너 오늘 일 모두 마쳤니 ? Did you finish today's two works ?

여름이 다 갔다.

Summer is gone almost.

우수운 꼴도 다 보겠네.

I am underestimated so that I am not happy.

비가 오니 내일 소풍은 다 갔군

Because it rains, so tomorrow's picnic may not be fun.